# VBA　SPLIT時に『ゞ』でエラーになる問題

Tags: vba

お世話になります。

ExcelやAccessのVBAで、文字列内に『ゞ』が含まれていると『文字列領域が不足しています』とのエラーが出る
問題、既に以前から取り立てられているとは思いますが、いまだにこの問題は根本の解決は
行われていないのでしょぅか。
現況のところ、エラーの出る直前で`str = Replace(str,"ゞ","")`といったことをして
回避させてはいますが、本質的にこのエラーが出なくなる方法はないのでしょうか。
この方法だと、結果的にデータを変更させてしまうため、よろしくありません。

もし、根本的な解決方法(Office自体に何らかの設定を加える等)がありましたらお教えください。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 3):

Officeの新しめのバージョンでは、そういった問題が起きないようです。
[こちらのサイト](https://hatenachips.blog.fc2.com/blog-entry-266.html) によりますと、

> どうやら AC2007から持ち込まれたバグのようです。
>   2010/03追記: Access2010でもこのバグは解消されていないようです。
>   2014/04/10追記: Access2013の最新バージョンでは解消されているようです。

とのことで、特定バージョンでのみ発生する不具合のようです。

また、手元のExcel 2013で以下のコードを実行してみましたが、やはりエラーは起きませんでした。

```
Sub SplitTest()
    Dim rec As String
    Dim a() As String
    rec = "7202.T,いすゞ自動車(株),4/30,303,"
    a = Split(rec, ",", , vbTextCompare)
    Debug.Print a(0), a(1), a(2), a(3), a(4)
End Sub
```

ということで、根本的な解決方法ということでしたら「ExcelやAccessのバージョンを上げる」ということになるのではないでしょうか。
古いバージョンのExcelやAccessについて、Microsoftが今更バグフィックスをしてくれるとも思えませんし。

Comment: すみません、今になって回答に気づきました。ありがとうございます。私の環境は2010なのですが、新しいVerなら治ってるということなら、まあ仕方ないのでしょうか。ありがとうございました。